# UILabel in a custom subview is not displaying the data

Tags: objective-c, ipad, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In my RootViewController, i instantiated a UIViewController (CheckOutCartVC) to be added as a subview of the RootViewController. I passed invoice model with "totalQuantity" property.
Here's the code:

```
CheckOutCartVC * checkOutVC = [[CheckOutCartVC alloc] init];
checkOutVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"checkOutVC"];
checkOutVC.invoice = self.invoice;

[self.checkOutView addSubview:checkOutVC.view];
[self.view addSubview:self.checkOutView];
```

The code above will add the CheckOutCartVC as a subview to my RootViewController. When I press the my checkout button, it will reveal this uiview coming from the right side (not covering the entire controller)

In my CheckOutCartVC, where i passed the 'invoice', i tried to log the _invoice.totalQuantity.
I'm getting the correct data (e.g., $20) through logs, but when I assign it to a LABEL, im only getting NULL.

```
- (void)setInvoice:(Invoice *)invoice{
    _invoice = invoice;
    NSLog(@"CheckoutCartVC Invoice   %@", _invoice.totalQuantity);
    self.lblTotalQuantity.text =  [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", _invoice.totalQuantity];
    return _invoice;
     }
```

I tried looking for solutions to my problem and tried adding

```
[self.lblTotalQuantity.text setNeedsDisplay];
```

I really don't understand why is this so. I'm getting correct logs but then when I assign the value to a label, it's giving me a NULL display.

Thanks.

Comment: How is your label created? With a XIB, so is it well linked? In your code, so in viewDidLoad probably, is it added to the VC.view?
As I understand your problem, it comes from a bad initialization of the label.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't mentioned about how you are adding the label! Cross check whether its being added to the view, check if its visible by setting a background color. If its being loaded from xib,check whether its outlet is connected or not.